# Is this tense possible?

Tags: grammar

What little had remained until recently of his ideals for the future has now perished.

Comment: Your sentence is probably technically okay, but you are being really unkind to your readers. There are so many different times implicated in the sentence that your readers will have a hard time working out its meaning. It might be a good idea to break it up into two or more sentences. How to do that would depend on the context and what you want to say exactly.

Comment: What little remained of his ideals for the future has now perished. // Check out English Language Learners SE.  That site would probably be more helpful for questions of this type.

Answer (score 1):

It feels like `until recently` is redundant in this sentence, and it would flow better simply as: `What little had remained of his ideals for the future has now perished.`